# displaying values from database into an html table

Tags: php, html

i want to display values from a database (a list of categories) into a table that has 2 columns and x number of rows.

I want my web page to display like this:

```
Apes Cats
Apples Cherries
Bats Tigers
Berries Zebras
```

Instead of

```
Apes Apples
Bats Bears
Cats Cherries
Tigers Zebras
```

Here is my code so far:

```
<table border="0" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="400" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY cat_name";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        while ($category = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $category['cat_name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: It's really interesting to see how many approaches can be taken on what's basically the same logic. Nice question ! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (haven't tested it though):

```
<table border="0" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="400" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY cat_name";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    # Calculate total rows and half rows, rounded up
    $full_row_count = mysqli_num_rows($data);
    $half_row_count = ceil($full_row_count / 2);

    $i = 0;
    while ($i <= $half_row_count) {
        # Set the result pointer for first column ...
        mysqli_data_seek($data, $i);
        $category_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

        # ... then calculate the offset for the second column ...
        $col_2_offset = $i + $half_row_count;

        # .. and make sure it's not larger than total rows - 1
        if ($col_2_offset <= $full_row_count - 1) {
            mysqli_data_seek($data, $col_2_offset);
            $category_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        } else {
            $category_2 = array('cat_name' => '');
        }
    ?>
    <tr>    
        <td><?php echo $category_1['cat_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $category_2['cat_name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic idea:

You get the count of the data via num_rows
Divide by two.
Now, the result of your division will be the number of rows.

Output a loop echoing value for row x and x+ num rows.  For example the output of line 1 would be :

```
<tr><td>$row[val1][data]</td><td>$row[val5][data]</td></tr>
```

So, your loop would ultimately output:

```
val 1  |  val 5
val 2  |  val 6
val 3  |  val 7
val 4  |  val 8
```

The loop should end when your incrementing variable = num_rows.  Should be pretty straightforward from there.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an another variable say, $i, to the loop and just increment this through as follows:

```
<table border="0" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC" width="400" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY cat_name";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        $i=1;

        while ($category = $data->fetch_row()) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>   
                <td><?php echo $category[1] ?></td>
            </tr>   
        <?php
        $i++;
        } ?>
    </table>
```

EDIT: Updated to fetch row data for each result and assume that cat_name is the second item in the array i.e. $category[1].

Comment: oops. I should have pointed out, i literally dont want it to look like numbers but i want the values (category names) from the database to come in that order. Sorry

Comment: OK, I've updated the original answer. This assumes that your table structure is cat_id, cat_name.  Hopefully this is closer to the mark.

Comment: it isnt, sorry for not being clear. I updated my question hopefully it'll make sense to you what im trying to ask now.

Comment: Do you have a  predetermined number of entries per column that you want i.e you show four in your example.  If so then you could look at utlising array_chunk().  Which would split the array into multiple arrays that you could then loop through.  Otherwise you could count the number of entries in the array and work when you need to start the next column.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be a table and your fine with browsers that support CSS 3, then you can use CSS columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/QKuDL/

Otherwise you'll need to sort the results first (untested - PHP is not my strong suit):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY cat_name";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$col_count = 2;
$max_items_per_col = ceil( mysqli_num_rows ( $data ) / $col_count );
$cols = array(array());

$col = 0;

while ($category = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
   if (count($cols[$col]) >= $max_items_per_col) {
     $col++;
   }
   $cols[$col][] = $category['cat_name'];
}
?>
<table> <!-- all of those attributes should be CSS instead -->
 <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $max_items_per_col; $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
       <?php foreach ($cols as $col) { ?>
         <td><?php if(isset($col[$i])) echo $col[$i]; ?></td>
       <?php } ?>       
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY cat_name";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$midpoint = ceil($data->num_rows / 2);
$i=0;

while ($category = $data->fetch_array()) {
  if ($i < $midpoint)
    $left[$i] = "<td>" . $category['cat_name'] . "</td>";
  else 
    $right[$i - $midpoint] = "<td>" . $category['cat_name'] . "</td>";
  $i++;
}

print "<table>";
for ($j=0; $j < $i; $j++)
{
    print "<tr>" . $left[$j];
    if (array_key_exists($j, $right)) print $right[$j];
    print "</tr>";     
}
print "</table>";
```

Comment: Wouldn't this throw an "undefined index" notice if the query result doesn't have an even number of rows ?

Comment: True, I added check that key exists